# How to insert a line break using a filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, line-breaks

This is my html for which I want the filter to execute:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-15 previewBtnCont" ng-repeat="category in NavigationModel.pageArray" >
                    <button class="btn btn-lrg previewContentBtns" >
                        <div ng-bind="category.categoryDescription|filterPreviewBtnLabels"></div>
                    </button>
</div>
```

The logic is that if the button label is more than 10 characters, then from 11th character onwards it goes to the next line. The filter I wrote is working but the line break "
" is displaying as a string rather than acting as a line break. The filter function is:

```
common.filter('filterPreviewBtnLabels', function () {
        var testString  = "Hello";
      return function(value){
        if (!angular.isString(value)) {
            return value;
        }
        return value + "<br>" + testString;
      };
});
```

If button label is Chicken it should display "Chicken" line break and then "Hello" but it is simply displaying "Chicken
Hello".

Any assistance is most welcome.

Comment: Note: </br> is the correct way to write a linebreak in HTML

Comment: Hey, this is CSS thing. Simple max-width & word-wrap should do the trick...

Comment: Kamil, I have a lot of logic besides a ax length thing. There was a need to add hyphen symbols after 10th character. Also, if multiple words are there needed to add a <br /> after every word etc. Hence I need a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to introduce `<br/>` into the text then you need to use `ng-bind-html` directive to output HTML, instead of `{{value}}`.

Assuming the source of the button text is trusted (i.e. not originally coming from the user or another third party source), you'd need to use `$sce` service to "trust" the resulting value as HTML: `$sce.trustAsHtml`.

Here's an example that puts `<br/>` instead of space:

```
app.filter("break", function($sce){
  return function(value){
    if (!angular.isString(value)) return value;
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(value.split(" ").join("<br/>"));
  };
});
```

And this is the usage:

```
<button ng-bind-html="name | break"></button>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N1ID9OvcfA0AhVPLU8Ry) to illustrate

Comment: You saved the day. Genius.

Comment: Deleted the other question.